# error '7' in VBA with Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, out-of-memory

I'm developing a Macro for VBA in Excel 2007

and there's a section which fills a ListBox with 11 columns.
Sometimes when I call this method for refilling the info appears a message which says:

> Se ha producido el error '7' en tiempo de ejecución: Memoria
>   insuficiente

in english is something like:

> There was an error '7' at Runtime: Insufficient memory

and the code points at this line of code:

> vList = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

I assured to release memory by setting all the objects used on this Function to Nothing

this is my full code:

```
Function llenarDatosTabla()

    Dim vList As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("PRODXSISTDATA")


    If (IsEmpty(ws.Range("A2").Value) = False) Then
        vList = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
        Me.ListBox1.List = vList
    End If

    Set vList = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Your assignment to `vList = ws.Range(...` statement is the wrong way of determining the last used cell in a range. The most likely reason for this error is that the resultant range is too big (because it is not what you *think* it should be).

Comment: I would suggest you to read this answer: [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: I get an 'Out of Memory' exception with an array size like: `vList = Range("A1").Resize(1048576, 32)`. I get similar error at `.Resize(2001, 16384)` so there appears to be some limit of around 33 million cell values that can store in an array.  This is tested on an empty worksheet in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Defines LastRow and LastCol seperately so you can ensure you are grabbing the correct range.

```
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
'Dim your other stuff

If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A2").Value) = False) Then
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Add this if still an issue to confirm correct LastRow and LastCol:
    'MsgBox "LastRow= " & LastRow & " LastCol= " & LastCol 
    vList = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
'etc etc etc
```